# Sql query is showing result in different way after migrating site to new server

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have site http://change.is, i migrate it to new server. Now one of the sql query is showing odd result. The query is below:

```
SELECT distinct group_concat(pm.meta_value separator ' ') as composer, group_concat(pm.meta_value separator '-') as composer_link FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm where (pm.meta_key='composer_fname_value' OR pm.meta_key='composer_lname_value') and pm.post_id in (SELECT p.ID FROM $wpdb->posts p where p.post_type='quote' AND p.post_status='publish') group by pm.post_id order by group_concat(IF(pm.meta_key='composer_lname_value', pm.meta_value,'')) ASC
```

Explanation:

I have meta fields like author firstname, author lastname (what i needed in this query) in the admin section for custom post type "quote". Before migrating to new server, this query is picking the author firstname &  then author last name. So output become like ( Seteve Jobs, Jeff Bezos). After migrating, i added new post for this custom type 'quote'. But now it is picking author last name & then author first name So output becomes like ( Diamandis Peter )

Point, it is picking this only for new post added, for old post in the database, it is coming fine.

Please help on this, or provide alternative query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to order the pm.meta_values(s) in the `group_concat` depending on their associated pm.meta_key. When pm.meta_key='composer_lname_value', the value should come first.

In this case, the easiest solution seems to use the optional ORDER BY clause of `group_concat`:

```
SELECT distinct 
 group_concat(pm.meta_value order by IF(pm.meta_key='composer_lname_value', 1,0) separator ' ') as composer,
 group_concat(pm.meta_value order by IF(pm.meta_key='composer_lname_value', 1,0) separator '-') as composer_link
 ... the rest of the query being identical...
```

Maybe that's what you wanted to achieve with the ORDER BY at the end of the query, but this sorts output lines, not contents inside the same line.

Comment: Hi, this query is working but i need to make little change in the output. I have to get output order by composer_lname_value, but using this query as order by IF(pm.meta_key='composer_lname_value', 1,0). it is giving the output order by composer_fname_value.

Please help on this